# virtual air-surface temperature difference above a water body

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science

I'm trying to work through the equations for the following paper:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2009JD012839/abstract

and am trying to understand the concept of virtual air temperature, virtual temperature of saturated air at the water surface, and virtual air-surface temperature difference. These play a part in calculating the stability of the atmospheric boundary layer.

I have a few questions regarding this work so instead of coming back and forth with multiple posts I'll include them all here.

This is the Monin Obukhov stability length scale

[image]

where Tv denotes the virtual air temperature which is defined by

[image]

where T is the air temperature, and qz is the specific humidity.

My first question is, how is the formula for the virtual air temperature derived? i.e. how do you end up at this equation.

Secondly, this formula gives the virtual temperature at the water surface:

[image]

where To is the water temperature, and qs is the specific humidity at saturation.

Similar to the first question, how do we arrive here?

Finally, the ratio of these values are given by:
[image]

What can this ratio be used for? I realise it must be something along the lines of determining the potential temperature profile above a water body but can it be used to determine the temperature at a given height (i.e. by knowing this profile)?

I realize that I am asking a lot but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about this subject, but in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monin%E2%80%93Obukhov_length), it is said that : "A physical interpretation of  is given by the Monin–Obukhov similarity theory. During the day  it is the height at which the buoyant production of turbulence kinetic energy (TKE) is equal to that produced by the shearing action of the wind (shear production of TKE)". It seems to be an empirical law, in this domain about turbulence and similarity theory,